Parsing 分岐点を認めたのと時を同じくして
The narrator is recounting how the character Ikalgo is sneakily driving a truck into an enemy aircraft hangar. He had previously sent his "Satellite Dragonflies", which are like drones, to scout out the area inside. When he reaches the crossroads that led to Areas A and B,
his Satellite Dragonflies had already
arrived at the warehouse:

＜ マルコスの情報によって場所を特定していたイカルゴは →
目的地に向かい約 ５ ｋｍ ほどの直線道路を →
トラックで駆けていた ＞
＜イカルゴの前方に  NＡ ・ Ｂ エリアへの →
分岐点を認めたのと時を同じくして →
「 サテライトンボ 」 が先に倉庫へたどり着いた
＞

I have trouble parsing 分岐点を認めたのと時を同じくして here. I think it is Ikalgo who recognizes the crossroads, but I have trouble understanding what 時を同じくして adds to the sentence. I know the phrase itself means "concurrently with (X)", but I don't know why you need to have the のと at all.
Is the の the nominalizer here or is it a time? 

You're one step short of getting it.
The の is the nominaliser. You need it because you have to turn the the 分岐点を認めた clause into a noun in order to attach と to it (case particles generally go on nouns; nothing special here).
The と is the "with" particle (specifically, it's the sub-case of と where it's used to indicate a "reciprocal relationship"; i.e. ～と同じ = "same as ～").
All in all, you get:

～と時を同じくして = "concurrently with ～" = "at the same time as ～"
分岐点を認めたのと　時を同じくして = "at the same tame as [the event of] Ikalgo recognising the fork"


My question then is why cannot you just use 時 (instead of の) since it is also a noun.

Hard for me to give a good reason "why" (it's just not the way the expression goes), but intuitively it does make sense to me. と here marks the event that gives you your time of reference, not the time. It basically feels like the same reason why we say "I arrived at the same time as he did" [〇] rather than "I arrived at the same time as the time that he did" [??] in English. All you're looking for is a semantically empty dummy noun, purely to use as "syntactic glue" (i.e. purely to allow the と to go on top). 時 carries unnecessary extra meaning, and sounds weirdly redundant/repetitive.
